# Bug with comments and answer poster

Tags: bug, comments, design, answers

I have recently came across a bug with the comments and the answer taking up the same space:

[image]

As you can see the comments is conflicting with the answer.

Can this be fixed?

<sup>Link to where I reproduced it: [What is different between `row[3:]` and `row[3]` when I handle csv data file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59606220/what-is-different-between-row3-and-row3-when-i-handle-csv-data-file)</sup>

Comment: [It displays fine for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84iPV.png).

Comment: **To close voters:** just because *you* can't reproduce a given problem doesn't mean that the question is not suitable for the site, or that the author can't reproduce it.

Comment: You should provide browers and OS info for things like this.

Comment: Are you using a [supported browser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) specifically I suspect you're using a version that's too old i.e. an old version of Firefox or Chrome or Safari that only supports grid with vendor prefixes (or doesn't support it at all).